# How to fix indentation / tab issue on Spyder

Tags: python, console, spyder, indentation

I'm trying to get the python shell to display this print statement without the large gap at the backslash. I have already tried going into Source > Fix indentation.

```
    print('\nAverage median \
           income in {:2s}: ${:<10,.2f}'.format(state, income))
```

```
Average median        income in MI: $51,601.37
```

Any guidance helps, thanks!

Comment: What forward slash? The one in your question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the tab before 'income' in ur code `print('\nAverage median \income in {:2s}: ${:<10,.2f}'.format(state, income))`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Spyder problem. It's your code. I think your backslash was intending to separate a line of code across two lines, but the backslash must be outside of your string, otherwise you're just escaping a space inside a string. If you must keep the code separated on two lines while preserving indentation, simply close your quotes and reopen them, keeping the backslash outside the quotes:

```
print('\nAverage median ' \
       'income in {:2s}: ${:<10,.2f}'.format(state, income))
```

```
Average median income in MI: $51,601.37
```